# Facebook api ios-sdk, delegates not working, fbDidLogin not called

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have a problem with the latest iOS sdk. I successfully login and the application comes back  but the delegation methods like fbDidLogin etc do not get called.

If tried it all in just one delegate file without any controllers and got it working. But if I have several controllers it's not working anymore/

I use my self written class `FacebookFetchter` to deal with Facebook.

```
    //FacebookFetchter.h
    #import Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "FBConnect.h"

    @interface FacebookFetchter : NSObject <FBDialogDelegate,FBSessionDelegate,FBRequestDelegate> {
        Facebook *facebook;
        FacebookFetchter *facebookFetcher;  }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;  @property (retain) Facebook *facebook; @property (retain) FacebookFetchter
*facebookFetcher; @end
```

```
    //  FacebookFetchter.m
    #import "FacebookFetchter.h"

    @implementation FacebookFetchter @synthesize facebookFetcher,facebook;

    -(void)login{
        NSLog(@"facebook login...");
        facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"..."]; //took the id out
        NSArray *permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                                  @"read_stream", @"offline_access", @"user_photos", @"user_photo_video_tags" , @"friends_photo_video_tags", @"friends_photos",@"friends_about_me",@"user_about_me",@"manage_friendlists",@"read_friendlists",@"user_birthday",@"friends_birthday", nil] retain];

        [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];

    }

    ...
    -(void)fbDidLogin {
        NSLog(@"Erfolgreich eingeloggt...."); } ...

    @end
```

In my delegate I implemented this and I also set up the plist with the fbapp_id url scheme

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url { 
    NSLog(@"AppDelegate handleOpenURL");
    return [[[settings facebookFetcher] facebookFetcher] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

there settings is my view controller:

```
//settings.h @interface Settings : UIViewController {
    FacebookFetchter *facebookFetcher;
    //Facebook *facebook; }

@property (retain) FacebookFetchter
*facebookFetcher;
- (IBAction)sync; @end

//settings.m @synthesize facebookFetcher;

//within this action the facebook login is called
- (IBAction)sync{
    NSLog(@"sync...");
    facebookFetcher = [[FacebookFetchter alloc] init];
    [facebookFetcher login]; }
```

Any suggestions??

Thank you!

Comment: Did u find out why this is happening?? i am having the same problem. The fbDidLogin method is not getting called

Comment: Removed my answer - is your `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url` method being called?  Breakpoint that.

Comment: this method is not called at my side same situation

Comment: I found the solution here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783782/fbdidlogin-not-called-ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783782/fbdidlogin-not-called-ios) open the facebook.m file and find the following line: [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES]; and change it to [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem and believe I may have found your solution.  When you create the app on facebook you must edit your app settings to allow for native ios app.  The ios bundle id selected must match EXACTLY to your bundle ID in the app you are creating.  Facebook states that they check this prior to authorizing your app.  Funny thing is if you remove the facebook app from the device and then try to authenticate it uses the web browser and seemingly bipasses this "security" completely.  Facebook doesn't send an error message back so it was a lot of fun to track down.  I figured I'd throw this answer out there in hopes to save some future devs some trouble.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - that really helped me! One uppercase letter costed me 2 days and would have costed me even more if it weren't for your answer.

Comment: Glad I could help cost me a couple days as well.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. For me it was solved by unchecking the "Application does not run in background" property in the Info plist.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I had not set the permissions for facebook access. I wrote an extra line of code

`NSArray *permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream",@"offline_access","publish_stream", nil] retain];`

Its working perfectly.