# Facebook iOS FbDidLogin not called 1st Time

Tags: ios, authentication, facebook-ios-sdk

I have a strange problem where FBDidLogin is not called the very first time I attempt an authorization with the Facebook App. I am using the latest Facebook iOS SDK from GitHub.

I have implemented this in my App Delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    return [[[SocialClass sharedSingleton] facebook] handleOpenURL:url];  
}
```

and the init of my `SocialClass`:

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"0000001234" andDelegate: self];
facebook.accessToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
facebook.expirationDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
```

and my didlogin method in the social class:

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSLog(@"facebook logged in");

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    // now let's grab the user info
    if(getFriends == YES)
    {
        [self getFacebookFriends];
    }
    else
        [self getUserInfo];
}
```

So again, my problem is the very first authorization attempt does not trigger fbDidLogin, only the 2nd attempt. I am getting the Facebook token printed correctly in the app delegate `openURL` method for *all* attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783782/fbdidlogin-not-called-ios) thread. Wish Facebook would explain this in the tutorial. Cost me half a day.