# Posting a picture on Facebook wall

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to post a picture on a Facebook wall in my iPad app. But nothing is happening, the Facebook site pops up to allow it, but an image is never posted. This is the code I have:

```
-(IBAction)facebookButton {
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId: APP_ID andDelegate:self];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults    objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [facebook authorize:nil];
    }

    [facebook authorize:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"publish_stream",@"user_photos", nil]];

    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"image.png"];
    NSData* imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                             @"Hey", @"message",  //whatever message goes here
                                                             imgData, @"data",   //img is your UIImage
                                                             nil];
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                         andParams:params
                                 andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                                     andDelegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put the post parts in the `fbDidLogin` method.

Also, this is completely irrelevant to your question, but it's something I noticed with the code you posted, you don't have to convert the image to NSData, if you want you can put the UIImage itself in under the key `picture` and it'll be uploaded.

Comment: Thanks! This in combination with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783782/fbdidlogin-not-called-ios#answer-6138046) got it working!